# Mini PC stick can be powered with mains power adapter (5 V/2 A) but not with power bank (also 5 V/2 A)?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-operated, powerbanks

I bought this product with the hopes of powering it with a power bank:

https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/products/boards-kits/compute-stick/stk1a32sc.html

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0868JZGPB

Now with its mains power adapter it works fine. The mains power adapter says it outputs 5 V/2000 mA.

So I figure why can't any of my power banks, with provide 5 V/2 A (or 2.1 A) power this mini PC? Tried with 2 different banks, both with 5 V outputs. Both can charge phones and do other things fine.

What happens is I plug them in to the power bank, then it seems to turn blue/lights on for a bit, but then it turns off after a few seconds and never boots up.

Any ideas why this would happen? Any other ideas how can I power this thing with a power bank / not a mains power adapter? That's specifically why I bought it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the device recognizes its wall outlet through DP/DM pins and latches itself down if it doesn't "like" the power source (e.g. your powerbanks).

Comment: Are you sure it's capable of providing 2-ish amps, or is it rated for 2000mAh and only provides 100-500mA at the port (USB standard)?

Comment: I don't know, but if it says "5V/2.1A" why wouldn't it be able to give that?

Comment: @JDS If it has multiple ports, it may be saying "2.1A total" across all the ports, some "power bank" manufacturers hype up numbers that way while actually being much lower.

Comment: There's a good chance the specifications of either the power source or computer are incorrect, or at least not capturing behavior of load peaks.  If you had one available, using a scope to watch for voltage drip / cutoff behavior would be interesting.  It is also worth keeping in mind that even if this worked, it would not run for very long.  Ultimately though this is a question about the *usage* of products rather than about electronic design, hence it is off topic here.